# Regex Multiple elements one string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string...

```
Out with the <_link>user://1|Team GB  for
<_link>tag://FridayBeers|#FridayBeers
```

And I have written the following regex which strips out the tags and characters.

```
~<(/){0,1}.*?( /){0,1}>|(tag://\w*\||user://[0-9]*\|)~
```

However what I now need to achieve is the following

`<_link>user://1|Team GB` gets converted to `<a href="user/1">Team GB</a>` and for `<_link>tag://FridayBeers|#FridayBeers` to `<a href="tags/FridayBeers">#FridayBeers</a>`

Can some post an answer that changes my regex to allow for this I am using PHP;

```
$post_text = "Out with the <_link>user://1|Team GB  for <_link>tag://FridayBeers|#FridayBeers";
$pattern = "~<(/){0,1}.*?( /){0,1}>|(tag://\w*\||user://[0-9]*\|)~"; //"~<(/){0,1}.*?( /){0,1}>|(tag://\w*\||user://[0-9]\|)~";
$replacement = " ";
$regexd = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $post_text);
```

Comment: You should probably have a look at [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: @kelunik thanks for the tip, could you post an answer with a code sample showing how you would do this, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php). The following code sample is just a minimal sample (see notice below).

```
<?php

$pattern = "~\<_link\>((?<typeUser>user)\://(?<userId>\d+)\|(?<userName>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?<typeTag>tag)\://(?<tagLink>[a-zA-Z]+)\|#(?<tagTitle>[a-zA-Z]+))~";
$string = "<_link>user://1|Team GB and <_link>tag://FridayBeers|#FridayBeers";

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) {
    if(!empty($match['typeUser'])) {
        return '<a href="user/'.$match['userId'].'">'.$match['userName'].'</a>';
    } else {
        return '<a href="tags/'.$match['tagLink'].'">'.$match['tagTitle'].'</a>';
    }
}, $string);
```

This code doesn't care about escaping HTML. Additionally the pattern only cares about names without spaces.

Comment: That seems to work well and thank you however some of the names as per the example have spaces in them for example my name `Justin Erswell` anyway of dealing with that?

Comment: You need something to make clear there's the end of the name. Imagine the following input: `<_link>user://1|Team GB was the ... team.` Should `was` stick to the name or not? How should your script know?

Comment: You are right of course this is a little tricky unfortunately I am stuck with the data. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this `preg_replace` code:

```
$s = '<_link>tag://FridayBeers|#FridayBeers';
$r = preg_replace('~<_link>([^:]+)://([^|]+)\|([\w -]+)~', '<a href="$1/$2">$3</a>', $s);
//=> <a href="tag/FridayBeers">#FridayBeers</a>
```